# Insert image in excel using xlsxwriter class. Odoo16

Tags: odoo, report, xlsx, xlsxwriter

I'm trying to display an image when exporting excel file in odoo 16.
Here is my code , but still not working.

Any help please ??

```
sheet.insert_image('A1', 'my_module_name/static/src/img/logo.png')
```

Thanks.

Comment: Did you check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50811051/odoo-image-in-excel)?